# how can I replace letter to certain number

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a huge data like the following

```
NDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSA 0
VCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLP 0
LTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFC 0
CQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWR 0
ITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSG 0
GHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNG 0
FLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTR 0
KGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQ 0
QSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVR 1
```

I want to use the following key to replace the letter with numbers

```
A   1
R   2
N   3
D   4
B   5
C   6
E   7
Q   8
Z   9
G   10
H   11
I   12
L   13
K   14
M   15
F   16
P   17
S   18
T   19
W   20
Y   21
V   22
```

at first I want to remove all the numbers close to letter and then replace the letters , so lets look at the first like

```
NDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSA
```

will have this

```
3 4 4 4 4 19 18 22 6 19 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1
```

and for the rest of lines the same as many lines as I have

Comment: If I may ask, what is the purpose of this conversion?  Trying to encrypt?

Comment: @karakfa yes, I want to encrypt it :-D

Comment: With bash and sed: `sed 's/ .*//' data.txt | sed -f <(sed 's|  *|/|;s|^|s/|;s|$| /g|' key.txt)`

Comment: Your example output appears to be missing a number.

Comment: Not efficient, but short: `perl -alpe '($_=$F[0])=~s/[A-Z]/(index("ARNDBCEQZGHILKMFPSTWYV",$&)+1)." "/ge'`

Comment: ... and why are there only 22 letters, what about the other four?

Comment: A little longer, but more efficient: `perl '-M5;%h=map{$_,++$i}split//,"ARNDBCEQZGHILKMFPSTWYV"' -alpe '($_=$F[0])=~s/[A-Z]/$h{$&} /g'`

Comment: @haukex not all alphabets have 26 letters. The Hawaiian alphabet only has 12 letters, for example. Even in alphabets that do have 26 letters it's not unusual to avoid some letters in some applications, e.g. you should generally avoid using the letter `O` in alphanumeric identifier strings since it looks too much like the number `0`. So there are various reasons why the OP may well just have 22 letters in his/her application.

Comment: @EdMorton *"So there are various reasons why the OP may well just have 22 letters in his/her application."* Yes, my question was *"why are there only 22 letters"*.

Comment: @Learner If you want to make sure that my above oneliners only replace those letters that are in the set, change `[A-Z]` to `[A-IK-NP-TV-WY-Z]`. Here is some code to generate such a set: `echo "ARNDBCEQZGHILKMFPSTWYV" | perl -MSet::IntSpan -ple '$_=Set::IntSpan->new([map{ord}split//,$_])->run_list;s/\d+/chr$&/eg;s/,//g'`

Comment: BTW, I used this question as the basis for a golfing challenge on PerlMonks: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1230284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    chars = "ARNDBCEQZGHILKMFPSTWYV"
    for (i=1; i<=length(chars); i++) {
        char = substr(chars,i,1)
        map[char] = i
    }
}
{
    out = ""
    chars = $1
    for (i=1; i<=length(chars); i++) {
        char = substr(chars,i,1)
        out = (out == "" ? "" : out " ") (char in map ? map[char] : char)
    }
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
3 4 4 4 4 19 18 22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1
22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1 22 17 13 12 10 13 17
13 19 20 18 10 3 4 19 6 13 21 18 6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6
6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6 18 21 10 13 19 7 1 11 10 14 20 2
12 19 3 4 14 10 11 4 10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10
10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10 13 16 16 13 6 10 3 10
16 13 6 10 3 10 22 21 14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2
14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2 21 13 19 13 3 1 18 8
8 18 22 6 15 7 6 8 10 11 10 7 2 12 18 17 14 4 2 6 14 18 6 3 10 2 14 12 22 2
```

Comment: I liked it already , I give it sometime to see what others give , but you are amazing

Comment: I have a silly question, if I want to pick up only the numbers at the end, how can I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pick up"? Are you referring to "the numbers at the end" of your input or your output or something else?

Comment: save only the numbers at the end of each line "the numbers at the end"

Comment: each input line or each output line? By "save" do you mean store them in an array or a variable or print them to a file or to stdout or something else? Please edit your question to clearly state what it is you're trying to do and include that expected output in your example there. Right now there's just too many things you might mean.

Comment: each input line . just remove the letters and save the data like `>out.txt`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm completely lost. Please update your question with an example.

Comment: done, I can do it like this `cat input.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' > out.txt`

Comment: Are you just trying to print the 2nd field of the input to a file? That's `awk '{print $2}' input.txt > out.txt`. You should google UUOC btw.

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -e'
    use autodie;
    my %charmap = (
        A =>  1, R =>  2, N =>  3, D =>  4, B =>  5, C =>  6, E =>  7, Q =>  8,
        Z =>  9, G => 10, H => 11, I => 12, L => 13, K => 14, M => 15, F => 16,
        P => 17, S => 18, T => 19, W => 20, Y => 21, V => 22,
    );
    while (<>) {
        s{(.)}{ ($charmap{$1} // $1) . " " }ge;
        print;
    }
' file
```

Or just

```
perl -pe'
    BEGIN { @charmap{ split //, "ARNDBCEQZGHILKMFPSTWYV" } = 1..22 }
    s{(.)}{ ($charmap{$1} // $1) . " " }ge;
' file
```

Comment: I liked your answer already !!! thanks

Comment: Didn't OP request that the number at the end of the line is stripped from the output? As-is the above solution prints the output with the trailing number intact.

Comment: The author permitting, I simplified their solution and added a much smaller one.

Comment: @Stefan, I think the question is unclear about that point. However, the OP's comments to Ed's answer seem to indicate those numbers are wanted.

Comment: While I appreciate the finer points of your latest game play for this particular hole in the SO Perl Golf Championships, I do have to contend the decision that the ball went into the hole: `34444191822613101928618201611061...`. Does that mean `3 4 4 4 4 19 1 8...` or `3 4 4 4 4 1 9 18...` or ...? I think you need another go on the putting green to sink it in.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative Perl solution:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %key = (
    A =>  1, R =>  2, N =>  3, D =>  4, B =>  5,
    C =>  6, E =>  7, Q =>  8, Z =>  9, G => 10,
    H => 11, I => 12, L => 13, K => 14, M => 15,
    F => 16, P => 17, S => 18, T => 19, W => 20,
    Y => 21, V => 22,
);

while (<STDIN>) {
    my($text) = /^(\w+)/;
    print join(' ',
               map { $key{$_} }
               split(//, $text)
          ), "\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Output with your given text:

```
$ perl dummy.pl <dummy.txt
3 4 4 4 4 19 18 22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1
22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1 22 17 13 12 10 13 17
13 19 20 18 10 3 4 19 6 13 21 18 6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6
6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6 18 21 10 13 19 7 1 11 10 14 20 2
12 19 3 4 14 10 11 4 10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10
10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10 13 16 16 13 6 10 3 10
16 13 6 10 3 10 22 21 14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2
14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2 21 13 19 13 3 1 18 8
8 18 22 6 15 7 6 8 10 11 10 7 2 12 18 17 14 4 2 6 14 18 6 3 10 2 14 12 22 2
```

---

#### On second thought...

As OP wants to obfuscate clear text then the more appropriate solution IMHO should be something like this:

```
$ bash <dummy.txt -c "$(echo /Td6WFoAAATm1rRGBMCtAbgBIQEWAAAAAAAAACsG0SbgALcApV0AOBlKq3igoJRmX9TqJifIRDIcDLdDtNRSv+tJBsifrrsdnlllNt2qqnlz0/uBmSnlO0FTKjKH/HXplJm9LaV7kXiNp/ZWDsyVqoV8EPjIEHHkXXd6jKahyq7tcCA4NGTHp/pwmk8jith6j/dcX67QCKmL0UtZUz9BqVWefD41lbrTNazbD8IP6zMLmAVxJav51SSTHzsUqhUfqhVmLsUg8sJkgloAAAAAAOMYtQXt21WNAAHJAbgBAABTvtYRscRn+wIAAAAABFla | base64 -d | xzcat)"
3 4 4 4 4 19 18 22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1
22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1 22 17 13 12 10 13 17
13 19 20 18 10 3 4 19 6 13 21 18 6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6
6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6 18 21 10 13 19 7 1 11 10 14 20 2
12 19 3 4 14 10 11 4 10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10
10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10 13 16 16 13 6 10 3 10
16 13 6 10 3 10 22 21 14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2
14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2 21 13 19 13 3 1 18 8
8 18 22 6 15 7 6 8 10 11 10 7 2 12 18 17 14 4 2 6 14 18 6 3 10 2 14 12 22 2
```

Comment: thanks, I liked it already

Comment: while the obfuscation is readily unobfuscated, the perl command is really slick.

Comment: And golfing fun for maximum line noise: `perl -ple's/\@.*//;tr/ARNDBCEQZGHILKMFPSTWYV/\x01-\x16/;$_=join" ",map{ord}split//'`

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
               {n=length($1); 
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                   printf "%s", a[substr($1,i,1)] (i==n?ORS:OFS)}' mapfile datafile

3 4 4 4 4 19 18 22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1
22 6 13 10 19 2 8 6 18 20 16 1 10 6 19 3 2 19 20 3 18 18 1 22 17 13 12 10 13 17
13 19 20 18 10 3 4 19 6 13 21 18 6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6
6 8 3 8 19 14 10 13 13 21 8 13 16 2 3 13 16 6 18 21 10 13 19 7 1 11 10 14 20 2
12 19 3 4 14 10 11 4 10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10
10 11 2 19 17 19 20 20 13 19 10 18 3 13 19 13 18 22 3 3 18 10 13 16 16 13 6 10 3 10
16 13 6 10 3 10 22 21 14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2
14 10 16 17 17 14 20 18 10 2 6 10 13 10 21 13 22 17 18 13 19 2 21 13 19 13 3 1 18 8
8 18 22 6 15 7 6 8 10 11 10 7 2 12 18 17 14 4 2 6 14 18 6 3 10 2 14 12 22 2
```

however, there is no provision of missing mappings that are not specified, i.e. if you have chars not listed on the mapfile they will be ignored.

If the goal is encryption I'll propose a different approach:

First let's generate a mapping (or encryption key)

```
$ key=$(printf "%s\n" {A..Z} | shuf | paste -sd' ' | tr -d ' ')

$ echo "$key"
CNYSGFRDKQTOXJVLEWBAHZPMUI
```

now you can encrypt/decrypt your file contents, simply

```
$ tr [A-Z] "$key" < datafile  > file.encrypted
```

and to reverse

```
$ tr "$key" [A-Z] < file.encrypted > file.decrypted
```

obviously, you need to save the key.

Comment: thanks, I liked it already